# Get UITextField value from a different xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I know how to get the text from of a `UITextField`, so that's not the problem. My problem is how do I get its value from a different XIB file?

For example: I have a name text field in my `Form.xib`, and I am trying to pull in that name value from `Chart.xib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `UItextField` a **IBOutlet** (@`property`) in its corresponding view controller (let say view A) ..then ..

lets says you want the value of text file in view B .

so in view B.

```
ViewA *viewA = [[ViewA alloc]initwithnibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];

NSString *textfieldtext = viewA.textfieldNamehere.text;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and I am getting an error:

`instance method '-initwithnibName:bundle' not found return type defaults to id`

It occurs on this line:
ViewA *viewA = [[ViewA alloc]initwithnibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];

Comment: AH! I figured out the error: initwithnibName needs to be capital letters- initWithNibName ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern well.
`.nib` file just representing user interface. `ViewController` must take care about all data that will be displayed into `View`(`.nib` file).